# how do I LUKS encrypt a drive that already has data?

Tags: centos, encryption, disk-encryption, luks

On a CentOS 7 server, I would like to LUKS encrypt the entire hard drive, including a 50GB partition that has already received `yum install` and a few other updates, but nothing else.  But [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/) says that typing `cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/xvdc` will result in the message `WARNING! This will overwrite data on /dev/xvdc irrevocably.`.

I do not want to wipe the hard drive.  I just want to encrypt it.  **What syntax do I use to LUKS encrypt the entire hard drive?**

The contents of the hard drive are summarized as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -T -h
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      ext4       50G  1.1G   46G   3% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G   49M  3.7G   2% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2      ext4      477M  106M  342M  24% /boot
/dev/sda1      vfat      200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3      ext4      1.8T   77M  1.7T   1% /home
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29379/discussion-on-question-by-codemed-how-do-i-luks-encrypt-a-drive-that-already-has).

Comment: Similar question on UNIX.SE: [Is there a way to encrypt disk without formatting it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444931/1131)

Answer (score 3):

You could make a full backup to another hard drive, then try this unofficial tool called [LUKS in-place conversion](http://www.johannes-bauer.com/linux/luksipc/).

But since you're already making a full backup to an external hard drive, you might as well go down the "official" route of copying the data out, creating a LUKS partition then copying it back. Tip: make sure you preserve permissions on both copy operations!

If you can't/won't make a backup before doing any in-place operations then you're braver than me and I hope you can afford to lose the data ;)

Comment: FWIW, on CentOS 8 there is the upstream supported [cryptsetup-reencrypt](https://manpath.be/c8/8/cryptsetup-reencrypt). Even newer cryptsetup versions feature a reencrypt command, cf. e.g. [crypsetup reencrypt (f31)](https://manpath.be/f31/cryptsetup/2.2.2-1.fc31.x86_64/8/cryptsetup#L167)